# How important are those hand seals really?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto we can see people make hand seals to do technique's. The further down the story we come the more neglected this becomes aka Naruto's rasengan does not need any hand seals to begin with. Minato also displayed the ability to form hand seals using a single hand.

So my question, how important are those hand seals anyway? How do they affect the juutsu they cast. And can evrybody do it with 1/0 hands if they train enough ?

Comment: Please view the related question here: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/33913/what-is-the-difference-when-a-jutsu-is-performed-by-weaving-only-some-of-its-se/33926#33926

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, as we know:

> While techniques may require a number of hand seals to work, a skilled ninja can use less or even one to perform the same technique.

So if you are a master shinobi, you can use a jutsu without making seals or making just a few seals, instead of 5-10-20. BUT if you are novice, you can't perform jutsu without hand seals. The number of seals or the number of hands indicates the skills of the shinobi. The more skilled someone is, the less effort he needs to put on casting a jutsu.

> An example of this is the Water Release: Water Dragon Bullet Technique, which requires a total of 44 hand seals to activate.Tobirama Senju, the Second Hokage, only needed to use one hand seal to complete the technique, a testament to his skill.Although rare, it is possible for a shinobi to be able to do hand seals with just one hand. The only shinobi seen so far capable of this are Haku, Minato Namikaze and Guren.

The seals are VERY important even if you're skilled. It's vital in the Shinobi World since a jutsu can't be performed without hand seals and just few of the jutstu's are casted without hand seals (e.g Rasengan).

Comment: you might want to add that female filler character from the spy village that performs the seals with her EYES

Answer (score 1):

Actually, hand seals are used to help the caster manipulate and control their chakra levels to execute the jutsu. Hand seals indicate how a shinobi can manipulate their chakra properly. However, a highly-skilled shinobi can perform a wide range of jutsu with one hand, or for some - no seals at all. The reason why is because some shinobi can manipulate chakra without concentrating it using hand seals at all. This can be particularly seen in Sasuke after he loses his arm during the Fourth Shinobi World War.