# What is the difference when a jutsu is performed by weaving only some of it's seals and when performed by weaving all of them?

Tags: naruto

Well, I noticed that plenty of times ,for instance Itachi performed the great fireball jutsu sometimes with one hand seal and some other times with all the ones necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weaving signs is a chakra manipulation technique that enables you to gather it in specific ways to execute specific techniques based off the chakra nature of the individual.

These signs are defined as `seals` and can be read about in the [seals wiki in narutopedia.](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hand_Seal)

As quoted in the wiki :

> While techniques may require a number of hand seals to work, a skilled ninja can use less or even one to perform the same technique.

It is also noted that some shinobi can master a technique so well that they can perform instantaneously without weaving signs but this takes years of training or an abnormally strong level of chakra control.

For instance Sasuke and chidori in the shippuden series is a common example of mastery as he learned to perform the technique seamlessly without needing time to weave.

Minato was also known for this with the flying raijin and rasengan.

As a shinobi masters a technique they are able to use less seals, one hand, and even no seals.

Comment: Correct me but wasn't Chiyo the first to make seals with one hand, that was pretty cool at the time.

Comment: Chronologically I'm not sure. But in the anime. Haku was the first to weave one handed in the bridge battle when they fought zabuza

Comment: Oh right, yes you are correct.

Comment: I don't think the rasengan is an example. It's just pure chakra, no hand signs are ever needed.

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade you are right the rasengan never used handsigns. I had a mistake in context because when naruto learned it he had to have a clone rotate his chakra for him which for some reason I remembered as seals. My answer has been edited.

Comment: Though to add in, I recall Naruto using weaving for the shadow clone jutsu and then not needing. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: The rasengan might be a good example when he mixes it with his fuuton chakra, he would normally need to weave seals yet,he doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you need to do a jutsu you need to wave the seals.As usually said in the movie that a shinobi who can't wave sign is useless. Itachi wave all the seals, maybe in the vedio or mangga it's not projected. Just like Kakashi, I've also seen him using the chodori or raiki without weaving..

Maybe that's the reason.

Comment: It'd be boring to see the hand seals every single time they use the jutsu. Besides, since the jutsu are formed using various hand seals, it would add workload to the animator.